# How to get Ajax content to bootstrap 4 tooltip?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am having difficulties to get Ajax content to the Bootstrap tooltip.
I can't share full code, because I don't know how to simulate Ajax call, but I will share as much as I can:

This next works if I place a static string instead getTooltip function:

```
      $('.sync').tooltip({
       delay: 50,
       placement: "bottom",
       title: getTooltip,
       html: true
      });
```

And here is original getTooltip function that doesn't work:

```
function getTooltip() {

  var elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

  var type = $(elementMouseIsOver).closest('tr').find("td").eq(type_desc_colIndex).text();
  var objName = $(elementMouseIsOver).closest('tr').find("td").eq(object_name_colIndex).text();
  var headDB = String($(elementMouseIsOver).closest('table').find("th").eq($(this).parent().index()).data('dynatable-column')).replace("cause_", "");
  if ($.inArray(type, SQLprocedures) !== -1) {
    execProc({
      procName: 'db_compare_execute_sp',
      Params: '{"@statement": ' + JSON.stringify("SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(\'" + objName + "\')) AS definition;") + '}',
      CallbackFunction: function (params) {
      var myRecords = params.Records;
        if (typeof myRecords.error !== undefined) {
          alert(myRecords.error);
        }
        else {
          return myRecords[0].definition;
        }
      },
      ConnectionString: headDB + 'ConnectionString',
      global: false
    });
  }
}
```

Return is actually returning, but it seems that tooltip doesn't wait for it. Is that the case?

Thanks,
Dejan

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've just found a solution for my original problem and that is to set the title in Ajax call:

```
          elementMouseIsOver.attr("title", myRecords[0].definition);
```